# Will I be able to identify the ATM surveillance footage from the bank where my money was stolen from?

Tags: security, atm, banking

I recently discovered unauthorized ATM withdrawals from an account I rarely use. The amounts were small ($40-100) over several months. I searched for my ATM card to this account and could not locate it. I called my bank and they put the money back, pending an investigation.

I suspect the culprit may be my new room mate.

My question is: Since the ATM that was used was actually in my own bank, will they call me in to identify the surveillance footage for those days? AND, will I get any of the money back that I did not notice months and months ago, or just the money that was taken in the last two days of my reporting it missing?

Comment: Did you ask the bank to look at the video?

Comment: Have you filed a police report? I doubt that bank would try to identify the thieves, it's the law enforcement job.

Comment: What country laws are likely to be different depending on your country.

Comment: Freeze your card (if that's possible in your country). Lodge a complaint with the police. Then dispute the transaction with the bank. In many countries, if no culprit is found you are held liable for the withdrawals --check your ATM card agreement for more details. Wish you the best.

Comment: Maybe you should change your PIN now. You're not supposed to give way your PIN, and you are supposed to change it if someone gets to know it.

Comment: Also don't post on the internet that you gave your PIN to someone. The bank may consider that a voluntary breach of security, and may decline to compensate you. And did we mention "don't tell anyone your PIN"?

Answer (score 5):

In the US, the bank won't provide you with footage, as that would subject them to liability if you decide to go vigilante. Also, keep in mind that the quality of the footage is often ridiculously bad.

Call the police.

Comment: ...and don't give your PIN to any more room-mates.